# If $a + b \sqrt{c} = d + e \sqrt{f}$ can we equate the numbers?

Tags: field-theory

Let $a, b, d, \text{ and } e$ be integers; Let $c \text{ and } f$ be positive integers greater than or equal to 2.

If the following is true:

- $a + b \sqrt{c} = d + e \sqrt{f}$
- $b \neq 0,  e\neq0$
- $c \text{ and } f$ are square-free.

Then is it true that $a=d, b=e,\text{ and } c=f $?

Edit: I added the condition that $c$ and $f$ are at least 2.

Comment: Please do not delete the question after receiving an answer.

Comment: "Has no repeated prime factors" is a bit strange.  Do you mean "are square-free"?

Comment: @lone student Sorry for deleting the original question.

Comment: @Brian Moehring, Yes, I'm not sure what the right term is but if the number under the square root has repeated prime factors, for example something like $\sqrt{12} = \sqrt{2^2 \cdot 3}$, we can simplify it to be $2 \sqrt{3}$. Edit: After looking up the definition for square-free integer, I think I meant square-free.

Comment: Definition of square-free: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer

Comment: I understood the question as you mean $\gcd(c,f)=1$

Comment: Note the special case of $c=f=1$

Comment: @Empy2 you are right. I added the condition that $c$ and $f$ are at least 2.

Comment: By the linked Lemma it is true more generally if $\,c,d,cd\,$ are all nonsquares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Rearrange and square to get
$$ e^2f=(a-d+b\sqrt c)^2=(a-d)^2+2(a-d)b\sqrt c+b^2c$$
and then the contradiction
$$\sqrt c=\frac{e^2f-(a-d)^2-b^2}{2(a-d)b}\in \Bbb Q $$
*unless* we are not allowed to divide by $a-d$. We conclude that $a=d$.
Thne $b\sqrt c=e\sqrt f$, so
$$ \sqrt{cf}=\frac{ef}b\in\Bbb Q$$
which means $cf$ is a perfect square, and as $c,f$ are square-free, this makes $c=f$. As they are also $\ne 0$, then the last eequality, $b=e$, is immediate.